# Existence of solution to Congruence relation $(x^2-2)(x^2-6)(x^2-3) \equiv 0\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences, quadratic-residues

I'm taking the final exam in "Number Theory" tomorrow and stuck with:

> Prove that  $\,\,\forall p\in\mathbb{Z}_p\,$ the congruence relation: $$(x^2-2)(x^2-6)(x^2-3) \equiv 0\pmod p$$ has a solution.

Here $p$ is an arbitrary prime number.

Any hints? Ideas?

Comment: Could yoou explain what is $p$?

Comment: $p$ is a prime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $p=2,$

$$(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)\equiv x^2(x^2-1)x^2\pmod2$$

But $x^2(x^2-1)x^2$ is divisible by $x(x-1)$ which being a product of two consecutive integers is always divisible by $2$

$$(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)\equiv0\pmod2 $$ for all integer $x$

For $p=3,$

$$(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)\equiv (x^2+1)(x^2)x^2\pmod3$$

But $3\nmid(x^2+1),$ so we need $x^4\equiv0\pmod3\iff x\equiv0$

For prime $p>3,$
Using [Legendre Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html) for prime $p$, $$\left(\frac6p\right)=\left(\frac3p\right)\cdot\left(\frac2p\right)$$

At least one of $\displaystyle\left(\frac6p\right),\left(\frac3p\right),\left(\frac2p\right)$ must be $=1$

Comment: $1$, or $0$.${}$

Comment: @barto, Consider $(x,6)=1\iff x\equiv\pm1\pmod6$

Comment: I was hinting at the case $p=3$, in which case $\left(\frac6p\right)=\left(\frac3p\right)=0$. We are not given this coprimality condition. (Strictly speaking, the Legendre symbol is not defined for odd primes so we would also have to take care of the case $p=2$ seperately. But this is just nitpicking, I confess.)

Comment: @barto, Thanks for your insightful feedback

Comment: Ah, you didn't _have_ to change that, now the answer looks less beautiful ;-)
(Note that the question asks for only one solution so we could get rid of those cases with $x=0$.)